# R: how to format data before applying cross-correlation

Tags: r, time-series, xts, cross-correlation

I want to do a cross correlation on two time series data sets.
The data sets looks as below.

```
> head(link420)
                  time diff420
1: 2018-01-01 08:00:00   18.50
2: 2018-01-01 08:05:00    0.00
3: 2018-01-01 08:10:00   -4.25
4: 2018-01-01 08:15:00    4.25
5: 2018-01-01 08:20:00   -8.50
6: 2018-01-01 08:25:00   47.00


> head(link423)
                  time    diff423
1: 2018-01-01 08:00:00   0.000000
2: 2018-01-01 08:05:00   1.700000
3: 2018-01-01 08:10:00 -22.818182
4: 2018-01-01 08:15:00  23.272727
5: 2018-01-01 08:20:00   4.160839
6: 2018-01-01 08:25:00  -9.337607
```

and the format of these two data sets are

```
> str(link420)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  31 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ time   : POSIXct, format: "2018-01-01 08:00:00" "2018-01-01 08:05:00" "2018-01-01 08:10:00" "2018-01-01 08:15:00" ...
 $ diff420: num  18.5 0 -4.25 4.25 -8.5 47 -20 4 -5 -27 ...
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> 


> str(link423)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  31 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ time   : POSIXct, format: "2018-01-01 08:00:00" "2018-01-01 08:05:00" "2018-01-01 08:10:00" "2018-01-01 08:15:00" ...
 $ diff423: num  0 1.7 -22.82 23.27 4.16 ...
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

How should I change these data formats?

```
when I try
ccf(link420,link433)

it returns an error

Error in dimnames(x) <- dn : 
  length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent
```

So I tried

```
link420<-xts(x = link420, order.by = link420$time)
link420<-link420[,c(2)]

link423<-xts(x = link423, order.by = link423$time)
link423<-link423[,c(2)]


but still gives an error

ccf(link420,link433)
Error in ccf(link420, link433) : univariate time series only
```

I want to find out at what time period (in 5 minute interval )these two data sets show correlations. Can I get some help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might find it easier to use `tsibble` objects like this.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(tsibble)
library(feasts)

link420 <- tibble(
    time = seq(as.POSIXct("2018-01-01 08:00:00"), length=100, by="5 min"),
    diff420 = rnorm(100)
  ) %>%
  as_tsibble(index=time)
link423 <- tibble(
    time = seq(as.POSIXct("2018-01-01 08:00:00"),length=100, by="5 min"),
    diff423 = rnorm(100)
  ) %>%
  as_tsibble(index=time)

inner_join(link420, link423, by = "time") %>%
  CCF(diff420, diff423)
#> # A tsibble: 33 x 2 [5m]
#>      lag     ccf
#>    <lag>   <dbl>
#>  1  -80m  0.0648
#>  2  -75m -0.0651
#>  3  -70m -0.0316
#>  4  -65m  0.0679
#>  5  -60m  0.0635
#>  6  -55m -0.158 
#>  7  -50m  0.0444
#>  8  -45m  0.0497
#>  9  -40m  0.0267
#> 10  -35m -0.0503
#> # … with 23 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2020-11-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Just few more questions 1) is normalization mandatory? 2) what does l=100 indicate?

Comment: l=100 is the length. I've now used the full argument name. Normalization does nothing as correlations do not depend on scale. Plot the results using autoplot(). See help(CCF) for an example.